# Is a new process needed for a new pam(_systemd) session?

Tags: linux, rust, systemd, pam

As an Experiment I am writing a small linux display manager. As references, I use lightdm, especially https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/blob/master/src/session-child.c, and the systemd documentation page https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-display-managers/ .

For the start, it allways manages tty9, and restarting after logout is handled by systemd (Restart=always).

So what the program does is

- show the login prompt (the "greeter" session)

  - start pam session for greeter
  - pam_authenticate the user
  - end pam session for greeter
- start the user session.

  - start pam session for user
  - fork, switch user, cd, exec

Lightdm uses two session-child process for this, but for simplicity I tried to do it in one.

When I comment out the session start for the "greeter", like here: https://github.com/TheJonny/textdm/blob/ba32d87f23816ef78763016b4c748a0875ae93f6/src/main.rs#L86, I am able to log in and start weston (starting the X server is currently not finished). If I do use a session for the greeter (lines 86 and 126 enabled), pam_systemd fails with the debug messages

```
Feb 23 01:30:09 io textdm[4084383]: pam_systemd(textdm:session): Asking logind to create session: uid=1001 pid=4084383 service=textdm type=wayland class=user desktop= seat=seat0 vtnr=9 tty>
Feb 23 01:30:09 io textdm[4084383]: pam_systemd(textdm:session): Session limits: memory_max=n/a tasks_max=n/a cpu_weight=n/a io_weight=n/a runtime_max_sec=n/a
Feb 23 01:30:09 io textdm[4084383]: pam_systemd(textdm:session): Not creating session: Already running in a session or user slice
```

It does not show up in loginctl, does not set $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, and then weston failes to start.

So my question is: can this (only) be solved by using separete processes? Is there another way to fully tear down the pam_systemd session?

(I am using the pam-client binding for rust, https://docs.rs/pam-client/0.2.0/pam_client/struct.Context.html#method.open_session should call `pam_open_session()` and `pam_setcred()`, and the drop should close the session and credentials.)

Answer (score 0):

to clean up, I answer my question.

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/756755d0fc5a0ef380416a54346b6438c3fb7ba5/src/login/pam_systemd.c#L1020

`pam_systemd` intentionally leaks a pipe file descriptor, and logind delays closing the session until this is closed, that is until the process using pam_systemd has exited.